# Integration in Maple

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, maple

I am trying to evaluate the following integral using maple but it returns the answer without evaluating the lower limit. Can anybody help me in using maple to solve this integral?

$$
\int_{0}^{R_{th}} {2\pi\lambda R e^{-\lambda \pi R^2}} D^{a\pi R^2} (a \pi R^2)^C dR
$$

Actually, the answer involves $R$ which is false. No term in the final expression should involve $R$.

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: I do not know Maple but I see a possible confusion. Could you try the same code replacing $D$ by $d$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Using both Maple 16 and 18, I entered the following commands:

```
Int(2*Pi*lambda*R*exp(-lambda*Pi*R^2)*D^(a*Pi*R^2)*(a*Pi*R^2)^C, R= 0..R[th]);
value(%);
```

And Maple responded with an answer that did not depend on $R$.

Note that **D** is reserved as the differentiation operator; however, in this case, its use as a simple name causes Maple no confusion.